# Venta con opciones específicas en Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Soy nuevo en Wordpress y estoy haciendo una página con Woocommerce, el cliente quiere algo que me tiene pensando en la parte de las ventas, es un restaurante de sushi.

El cliente tiene 15 sabores diferentes, pero ellos venden por combos, 4 para ser exacto y cada combo le da derecho a escoger un número determinado de sabores.

La idea es que el cliente seleccione un combo y que también le permita seleccionar el número de sabores que el combo especifique, por ejemplo, el combo 1 tiene que seleccionar 3 sabores de los 15, sólo 3 y pues no se como hacerlo.

Si alguno me puede dar una guía de como hacerlo o si hay algún plugin que lo haga, estaría muy agradecido.

Por cierto, estoy usando el Theme Xstore.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que estás buscando es vender productos variables, te dejo la documentación de woocommerce https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/producto-variable/
Tendrías que poner en la primera opción los diferentes combos y en las siguientes opciones que se puedan elegir (los sabores), asi el cliente elige de la opción uno los combos, de la opción de 2,3 y 4 los tres sabores disponibles para ese combo. Puedes personalizar las posibles combinaciones para limitarlo desde la sección variaciones dentro del producto en woocommerce.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que la pregunta está basada en opiniones, por lo tanto trata de no responder a este tipo de preguntas, o a las que son de baja calidad. Lee [answer].